# Check if same text has been entered two times or more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm practicing JavaScript with the jQuery library.
What I want is to create something like a **POS Application**, but there are things I just can't figure out.
I'd like to, if you enter `lays`, and then you enter `lays` again, the output should change to the already appended output to `lays * 2`.
I'm kind of lost on how to achieve the desired.
What I have so far:

```js
var billoutput = document.getElementById('inputterminal');
var counter = 1;

$('#bill').click(function() {
  $("#holder").append(" <span style='padding:10px; margin:5px; color:white; background-color:black; border-radius: 10px;'> " + billoutput.value + " </span> ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>POS Terminal</h1>
<input id="inputterminal" value="" name="" type="text">
<button id="bill">bill</button> <br>
<div style="margin-top: 20px;" id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: What means `lays * 2` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan "lays x2"

Comment: Off topic: consider using css classes for your style instead of a nasty long `style=` don't even need a class on the appended html, eg `#holder > span { padding:10px;...`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the inputs in an array and check whether the array includes the value of the input every time the user clicks the button. If it does not, append the element and push the input's value to the array.

```js
var billoutput = document.getElementById('inputterminal');
var counter = 1;

var words = []

$('#bill').click(function() {
  if (!words.includes(billoutput.value)) {
    words.push(billoutput.value)
    $("#holder").append(" <span style='padding:10px; margin:5px; color:white; background-color:black; border-radius: 10px;'> " + billoutput.value + " </span> ");
  }else{
    alert("you already entered that!")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>POS Terminal</h1>
<input id="inputterminal" value="" name="" type="text">
<button id="bill">bill</button> <br>
<div style="margin-top: 20px;" id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: I agree but the use of a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here in place of the array would be more efficient. Also, may want to toLower() the entries if casing does not matter.

Comment: @AlienWithPizza How would it be more efficient? You would still have to check whether the Set includes the value.

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#performance) - "In particular, it is, on average, faster than the Array.prototype.includes method when an Array object has a length equal to a Set object’s size."

Comment: Sounds like micro-optimisation - even nano-optimisation.   You won't see a difference as it would be smaller than pressing enter quickly vs slowly - ie it's user dependent.  Always worth being *aware* of alternatives of course.

Comment: I'd agree with that, it is completely negligible in this use case. Just the right tool for a job. If we where to write this on the back end in say C#, I'd say use a Hashset<string>().